# Segmentation Fault when using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

My main program in Keras and Tensorflow hits a seg fault

```
python fine-tune.py --train_dir /root/data/train_dump/ --val_dir 
/root/data/val_dump/ --nb_epoch 100 --batch_size 32
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:root:Keras version 2.2.2 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible of Keras is 2.1.3 .
WARNING:root:TensorFlow version 1.10.0 detected. Last version known to be fully compatible is 1.5.0 .
Found 2976 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 1100 images belonging to 4 classes.
2018-09-06 23:28:06.891710: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-06 23:28:08.030896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: TITAN V major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.455
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0
totalMemory: 11.78GiB freeMemory: 11.36GiB
2018-09-06 23:28:08.030988: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-06 23:28:08.688955: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-06 23:28:08.689049: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2018-09-06 23:28:08.689071: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-09-06 23:28:08.689614: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10974 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN V, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
Epoch 1/100
2018-09-06 23:29:31.853354: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018-09-06 23:29:31.853522: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:360] Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.30.0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Yet tensorflow appears to be okay via this tf.session() test:

```
In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
   ...:
   ...: with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
   ...:     a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
   ...:     b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
   ...:     c = tf.matmul(a, b)
   ...: with tf.Session() as sess:
   ...:     print(sess.run(c))
   ...:
2018-09-06 23:37:31.603090: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-06 23:37:32.765804: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: TITAN V major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.455
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0
totalMemory: 11.78GiB freeMemory: 11.36GiB
2018-09-06 23:37:32.765866: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-06 23:37:33.358184: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-06 23:37:33.358276: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2018-09-06 23:37:33.358295: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-09-06 23:37:33.358793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10974 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN V, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]]
```

Thinking maybe the warnings had something to do with it, I did give that a try.

```
Installing collected packages: keras
  Found existing installation: Keras 2.2.2
    Uninstalling Keras-2.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Keras-2.2.2
Successfully installed keras-2.1.3
(fastai) root@607b0f29-ad6b-482c-aead-aeae0a84fe2f:~# python fine-tune.py --train_dir /root/data/train_dump/ --val_dir /root/data/val_dump/ --nb_epoch 100 --batch_size 32
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 2976 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 1100 images belonging to 4 classes.
2018-09-07 00:30:10.722085: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-07 00:30:11.880320: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:
name: TITAN V major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.455
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0
totalMemory: 11.78GiB freeMemory: 11.36GiB
2018-09-07 00:30:11.880388: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN V, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
Epoch 1/100
2018-09-07 00:30:51.858613: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018-09-07 00:30:51.858965: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.30  Wed Jan 31 22:08:49 PST 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5)
"""
2018-09-07 00:30:51.859055: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:393] possibly insufficient driver version: 390.30.0
2018-09-07 00:30:51.859099: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I find weird things like this happen after system updates and often resolve themselves after a reboot. Probably not the case, but worth a try if you haven't already...

Comment: It appears that TensorFlow is not being able to use your Titan V. If you recently updated the GPU driver it could be that you need to reboot, as suggested by DomJack. If you keep seeing the same errors after that, it could be that the driver or CUDA is not correctly installed. Also [TensorFlow isse #6698](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6698) has a long discussion about `CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED`.